# Подсчёт количества статей или материалов по каждой категории

Tags: php

В общем, доброго времени суток. Вдруг задумался о такой вещи, как подсчёт количества статей в категории и вывода их на сайте в блоке. Допустим, у меня есть таблица, в ней - строка с количеством статей в данной категории. Есть метод, который подсчитывает это количество, и второй метод, который обновляет строку с результатами в таблице в виде просто вывожу это кол-во. Получается, что каждый раз при загрузке любой страницы проходит куча лишних запросов. А ещё как-то это можно реализовать? Вот, допустим, тут на hashcode.ru при просмотре в блоке справа идёт подсчёт меток и вывод. Как это тут реализовано, может, кто знает? Очень интересно будет послушать вас. Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ...Есть ещё предложения?))

Comment: Хочу понять, как сделать максимально правильно)

Answer (score 1):

А зачем сначала считать количество связанных статей, потом записывать это куда-то в базу? Если нужен вывод статей в блоке - просто через JOIN выбираем связанные, для получения количества считаем count массива выбранных. По другому можно COUNT(*) посчитать сразу в MySQL.